# Get all application soft keyboard key press text in android

Tags: android, keyboard, actionlistener

I have to create app like key logger mean anywhere in android device if keyboard is open i need to get key press text and set it to logger .Is it possible ? If yes then please help .I have no idea how to start it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to do this is to create your own `InputServiceMethod`. If you don't want to record any passwords, you can create an `AccessibilityService` to get text from any fields on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I just know, some way but whether it will be helpful or not I don't know. You can create your own `InputMethod` and record the keypresses, here is a link on how to create `InputMethod` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html.